# Symfony 1.4/doctrine schema.yml many to many relations does'nt work properly?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a little disturbing problem in here!
an using symfony 1.4 with Doctrine!
i fact i have a "many to many" relation (see code bellow) but i don't have the RIGHT result!

```
     Monitor:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    label: {type: string(45)}
    url: {type: string(80)}
    frequency: {type: integer}
    timeout: {type: integer}
    method: {type: enum, values: [GET, POST]}
    parameters: {type: string(255)}
  relations:
    Server:
      foreignAlias: Servers
      refClass: Benchmark
      local: monitor_id
      foreign: server_id

Server:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    name: string(255)
    ip: string(255)
  relations:
     Monitor:
      foreignAlias: Monitors
      refClass: Benchmark
      local: server_id
      foreign: monitor_id

Benchmark:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    monitor_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    server_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    connexionTime: {type: string(45)}
    executionTime: {type: string(45)}
    responseTime: {type: string(45)}
    responseCode: {type: string(45)}
    responseMessage: {type: string(45)}
  relations:
    Monitor:
      local: monitor_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Monitors
    Server:
      local: server_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Servers
```

1- when in the add server (or monitor) interface there is a list of monitors (or servers) that appears (but i can add a server(or monitor) without selecting it.

2- when in the add benchmark interface, i don't have the monitors and servers list in order to select them! and when i submit  i doesn't work (it should'nt any way!). i get this error:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sfmonitoring`.`benchmark`, CONSTRAINT `benchmark_monitor_id_monitor_id` FOREIGN KEY (`monitor_id`) REFERENCES `monitor` (`id`))
```

i have this code in the **BaseBenchmarkForm** class

```
    abstract class BaseBenchmarkForm extends BaseFormDoctrine
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'monitor_id'      => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'server_id'       => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'connexionTime'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'executionTime'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'responseTime'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'responseCode'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'responseMessage' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'created_at'      => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
      'updated_at'      => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
    ));

    $this->setValidators(array(
      'monitor_id'      => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('monitor_id')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('monitor_id'), 'required' => false)),
      'server_id'       => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('server_id')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('server_id'), 'required' => false)),
      'connexionTime'   => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 45, 'required' => false)),
      'executionTime'   => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 45, 'required' => false)),
```

ANY IDEAS GUYS ??????
Pleaaaaaase am really Blocked !

############################################### V2

Thank you for the Help, it really means to me!
I did theses transformations:

```
 Monitor:
      tableName: monitor
      actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        label: {type: string(45)}
        url: {type: string(80)}
        frequency: {type: integer}
        timeout: {type: integer}
        method: {type: enum, values: [GET, POST]}
        parameters: {type: string(255)}

    Benchmark:
      actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        monitor_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
        server_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
        connexionTime: {type: string(45)}
        executionTime: {type: string(45)}
        responseTime: {type: string(45)}
        responseCode: {type: string(45)}
        responseMessage: {type: string(45)}
      relations:
        Monitor: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: monitor_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Monitors }
        Server: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: server_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Servers }

    Server:
      actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        name: string(255)
        ip: string(255)
```

But in the benchmark "new" interface, i still don't get the servers and the monitors list!

Comment: i modified my question, please read it, i didn't get the right result on the benchmark new interface !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, take two: The (SQL) error your getting means that the `Benchmark` you want to save, has an invalid `monitor_id`. So it's either empty or refers to a non-existing monitor.

This probably happens because you didn't select a monitor/server, because they were invisible on the form (they are rendered as `sfWidgetFormInputHidden`).
To show the `<select>`s for these two, you have to go to the `BenchmarkForm` (which overrides the `BaseBenchmarkForm`, and override the `configure()` method. Something like this:

```
public function configure() {
  parent::configure();
  $this->widgetSchema['monitor_id'] = sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Monitor'));
  $this->widgetSchema['server_id'] = sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Server'));

  $this->validatorSchema['monitor_id'] = sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Monitor'));
  $this->validatorSchema['server_id'] = sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Server'));

}
```

Comment: when submitting the benchmark it says that the monitor and the server's values in the field are not valid

Comment: You also need to update the validators. See my updated code sample. :-)
(And don't forget to accept my answer if it works ;-) )

Comment: if yes! please i have another problem in the same way but with SfGuardGroup table that am using in a many to many relation!
I'll post it in minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Your `refClass` definition in the `Server` relations, can only point to a model with two fields: one field for each of the owning sides (in this case `Server` and `Monitor`). By creating a Many-To-Many relation this way, you can call `$server->Monitors`, and automatically uses this `refClass` to create a collection of `Monitor` (and not `Benchmark`). (As a user you don't see the refClass).

If you want to have more data in this 'coupling class' `Benchmark`, like you do, you'll have to work with to separate relations.

Just drop the relation in the Server and you'll probably be done.

Comment: Please read the question i modified it because i still can't replay mes own questions !